# How can I do a left join in Spring data rest Querydsl?

Tags: spring, left-join, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I want to do a search for a person where "postcode" matches my search term (e.g. "133") in either of his two addresses. I am using Spring Data Rest and using QueryDsl.
I need a "left outer join"

The problem: the generated query only generates results where the person has BOTH addresses.
If they only have one then they do not come into the set from which the further selection on postcode is made.

How do I create a "left join"?

I have a "Partner" Object with two addresses: 'main' and 'post' in a OneToOne relationship:

```
public class Partner {
...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAINADR_UUID")
    private Adresse hauptanschrif;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "POSTADR_UUID")
    private Adresse postanschrift;
...
}
```

I have a Partner Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "partner", collectionResourceRel = "partner")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Partner, String>,
   QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Partner>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QPartner> {

with "customize()"
@Override
default public void customize(
    QuerydslBindings bindings, QPartner qPartner) {

...
// Predicate macht ein hauptanschrift.plz OR postanschrift.PLZ test
        bindings.bind(qPartner.hauptanschrift.postleitzahl).as("postleitzahl").first(
  (path, value) -> {
    value = value.replace("*", "");
    final BooleanExpression partnerPlzPredicate = 
    partnerPredicatesBuilder                         
      .with("hauptanschrift.postleitzahl", QDslOperation.STARTS_WITH, value)                             
      .with("postanschrift.postleitzahl", QDslOperation.STARTS_WITH, value)
    .buildPlzExpression();
    return partnerPlzPredicate;
}); // 1
```

The JPQL generated for the predicate is (e.g.):
    false = true || startsWith(partner.hauptanschrift.postleitzahl,133) || startsWith(partner.postanschrift.postleitzahl,133)

The sql generated (for oracle) is (simplified):

```
select <list>
from partner partner0_ 
cross join adresse adresse1_ 
cross join adresse adresse2_ 
where 
partner0_.hauptanschrift_uuid=adresse1_.uuid and 
partner0_.postanschrift_uuid=adresse2_.uuid 
and (1=0 
or lower(adresse1_.plz) like '133%'  
or lower(adresse2_.plz) like '133%' )
```

I need something like the following to be generated:

```
select <list> from partner partner0_ 
left outer join adresse adresse1_ on (partner0_.hauptanschrift_uuid=adresse1_.uuid)
left outer join adresse adresse2_ on (partner0_.postanschrift_uuid=adresse2_.uuid);
where (1=0 
or lower(adresse1_.plz) like '133%'  
or lower(adresse2_.plz) like '133%' )
```

Comment: `partnerPredicatesBuilder` is an instance of what?

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl Section 6
It is a class for building Predicates